# ProgressBar does not show before dialog open Android Java

Tags: java, android

```
 progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String linkText;
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            try {
                linkText = generateLink.sendLink("1234");
            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            dialog.show();
    });
```

When I click the button share and the listener is triggered, I see the dialog open and no pregressBar is visible before this. If I remove dialog.show() and setVisibility(View.GONE) the progressBar showing after 2-3 second.generateLink.sendLink() function need 2 second to return a value I want the progress bar to be visible till generateLink.sendLink() function return the value to the linkText string any help will be welcome.I am new in Android.

Comment: You need to read about Tasks and Threads, you are trying to make a "linear" programming, that doesn't work like that on Android.,

Comment: I take a look but I can't find a way I try with Threads, with handler post delay and I  can find a way when I click on the button progressBar to display till sendLink function return a valur.Any help will be welcomed